# How can I solve it

Tags: javascript, arguments

https://codefights.com/fight/vHc2D9mSkSsP6sdqj

```
function myConcat(arguments, separator) {

}
```

For arguments = `["Code", "Fight", "On", "!"]` and separator = `"/"`, the

**output**

```
 "Code/Fight/On/!/"
```

Answer (score 2):

Simply Do with [`Array#join()`](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwibqbL8x4_UAhVEN48KHQJfDBwQFggsMAE&url=https%3A%2F%2Fdeveloper.mozilla.org%2Fen%2Fdocs%2FWeb%2FJavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FArray%2Fjoin&usg=AFQjCNFpvATQJoPTs0sJsk78ojioE7D3Xg&sig2=N2knN-9K4ItM175tgXyItA) method `+separator` used for added `separator`  at end

```js
function myConcat(arguments, separator) {
        return arguments.join(separator)+separator
    }

console.log(myConcat(["Code", "Fight", "On", "!"] , "/"))
```

Answer (score 2):

First of all please do not use [`arguments`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) as an own variable, especially not in as part of argument of a function, because functions have a local variable with the name `arguments`, which contains all arguments of the function. The build-in `arguments` is an array like object, which is iterable.

To get the wanted string, you could use [`Array#concat`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) to concat the array with an empty string and perform a [`Array#join`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join).

```js
var array = ["Code", "Fight", "On", "!"],
    string = array.concat("").join("/");

console.log(string);
```